# Проверка всех значений списка на false и если все значения False то должны вернуть также False

Tags: python

Задача сделать функцию, по условиям которой необходимо проверять список с булевыми значениями, и если в списке все значения True или хотя бы одно значение True, то возвращать True, если же в списке все значение False то необходимо возвращать булевое значение False. Первую часть сделал без проблем, а вот с выводом False, не получается.

```
def all_targets_hit(attempts_for_each_target: list) -> bool:
    if all(attempts_for_each_target) or any(attempts_for_each_target):
        return True
    if not any(attempts_for_each_target):
        return False
```

Comment: def ....: return any(attempts_for_each_target) - Один return в функции

Comment: Вы делаете совсем не то! Вам даётся СПИСОК СПИСКОВ, а не просто список. И вернуть надо True, если в каждом из подсписков есть хотя бы один True. Посмотрите на автотесты, которые вам даны.

Comment: `all(map(any, attempts_for_each_target))`

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать так:

```
def all_targets_hit(targets):
    return all(any(target) for target in targets)
```

Вариант без использования `all`, `any`:

```
def f(targets):
    def check_target(target):
        for hit in target:
            if hit:
                return True
        return False

    for target in targets:
        if not check_target(target):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Первый вариант немного подкорректировал и прошло: return all([any(hit) for hit in hits]). Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно сделать проще:

```
def foo(a: list[bool]) -> bool:
    return any(a)

a = [True, False, False]
print(foo(a))
```

Или так

```
def all_targets_hit(hits) -> bool:
    return any([any(hit) for hit in hits])


hits = [
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
]
 
print(all_targets_hit(hits))
```

Comment: Не получается, может я не корректно указал условия. Вот оригинал условий задачи: Напиши функцию all_targets_hit, которая принимает результаты выстрелов в каждую мишень.
Результаты – это список, каждый элемент которого является списком булевых значений, соответствующих результатам выстрелов в одну из мишеней. Если значение True, то значит данным выстрелом мишень была поражена, если False, то значит нет. Таким образом, если в списке хотя бы одно значение True, то мишень была поражена, если все False, то нет.
Функция all_targets_hit возвращает True, если все мишени были поражены

Comment: @Константин исправил

Comment: Все равно два автотеста не пропускает. Первый: attempts = [[True, True, True], [False, False]], expected_result = False AssertionError: assert all_targets_hit(attempts) is expected_result, ( f"Function 'all_targets_hit' should return {expected_result} " f"when attempts are equal to {attempts}" ). Второй: attempts = [[True, True, True], [True], [False, False], [False, False, True]]
expected_result = False AssertionError: assert all_targets_hit(attempts) is expected_result, ( f"Function 'all_targets_hit' should return {expected_result} " f"when attempts are equal to {attempts}" )

Comment: Замените `any` на `all`

Comment: Заменил не помогло :(

Comment: any([any(hit) for hit in hits]) следует писать как any(any(hit) for hit in hits) создавать дополнительный список тут не к чему

Answer (score 0):

такое короче писать функциональщиной

```
all(map(any, hits))  # [[True, False], [True]] -> True
```